# List operation to summarize and shrink down list with sublists

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list which basically looks like this:

```
[[A, B], [A, C], [D,E]]
```

where A, B, C, D and E are nodes of an electrical circuit.
When two nodes are together in one list, they are at the same potential, so in my case, A and B, A and C, and finally also D and E are basically equal.

Because A and B, but also A and C are equal, also B and C should be equal.

What I want to do is the following:
I need to create a list which basically looks like this:

```
[[A, B, C], [D,E]]
```

So it should summarize all nodes which are basically equal into one list and put every list of equal nodes into a final list like the one above.
I was thinking about using sets, for example by using intersection and union, but I have not figured it out already.

Maybe somebody can help and thanks in advance!

**[Edit]**
This is my attempt so far:

```py
wireEnds = self.wireEnds.copy()
for currentNodePair in wireEnds:
    foundInSubSet = False
    print("currentNodePair:",currentNodePair)
    for subSet in self.commonNodes:
        print("subSet:",subSet)
        if (currentNodePair[0] in subSet) or (currentNodePair[1] in subSet): 
            subSet.add(currentNodePair[0])
            subSet.add(currentNodePair[1])
            print("Adding to subset:",currentNodePair)
            foundInSubSet = True
            continue
    if not foundInSubSet:
        print("Not found, creating new subSet:",currentNodePair)
         self.commonNodes.append({currentNodePair[0], currentNodePair[1]})
```

Note that I'm using sets instead of sublists because I don't want duplicates in my sublists.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I was not done, I posted my question too early, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you have is a graph and you want to find [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)), you can use Networkx which has an implementation of union find datastructure:

```
from networkx.utils.union_find import UnionFind
sets = UnionFind()
for gp in lst:
    sets.union(*gp)
out = [list(s) for s in sets.to_sets()]


[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['E', 'D']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks @enke, this is by far easier than my solution, but maybe you can have a look!

```py
def version_3(list_in):
  output = [set(list_in[0])]
  for sublist in list_in[1:]:
    current_set = set(sublist)
    found_in = []
    for group in output:
      current_group = set(group)
      if current_set.intersection(current_group):
        found_in.append(current_group)
    
    if found_in:
      for group in found_in:
        output.remove(group)
        current_set = current_set.union(group)
      output.append(current_set)
    else:
      output.append(set(sublist))
      
  return output
```